# Unicode-math: Stylistic setting fails for super/sub-scripts

Tags: math-mode, fonts, unicode-math

I am using XeLaTeX to compile a document with usage of the package `unicode-math` in order to make my document looks satisfying. However the target stylistic setting fails for super/subscripts as the following MWE shows:

```
% !TEX Program = xelatex 
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont[StylisticSet = {02,08}, mathit = sym]{STIX Two Math}
\begin{document}
    \[
          g, u, v, w, z, \int_{g,u,v,w,z}^{z,w,v,u,g}, \int_\int^\int
    \]
\end{document}
```

It produces

[image: Results]

and the Stylistic Sets are as shown in the font table document:

[image: Stylistic Sets]

Obviously, Stylistic Set 02, 08 didn't apply to super/subscripts, so my questions is:

> Is it a drawback of this `unicode-math` package or I used the package incorrectly? Any workarounds to keep the consistency of font styles of both regular math text and super/subscripts [i.e. these stylistic settings applies to both regular math and super/subscript characters]?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

running it with `lualatex` and an up-to-date TexLive I get:

[image]

so it looks more a problem with `xelatex` ...

Comment: Wow, thanks! Another question: are you familiar with the "script-feature" option etc. of the package `unicode-math`? Any possibility for the same output still under `xelatex` by tweaking this option [maybe also other related ones]? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by using the script feature?

Comment: I think it is the section 4.2 of the user document of the package `unicode-math`.  Seems that this option could control the fonts of subscripts and subsubscripts. But the document does not have a detailed explanation on this. I don't know whether it is something related to OTF features themselves.